# How do I annotate several points to the same text box with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I'm not sure how to annotate several points to the same text box. I found a (very) dirty way of doing it by just placing all my text boxes at the same position, so it basically just write over the same spot but I would prefer to do it correctly.

Here is what I currently do:

```
def my_annotate(p, s, xy_arr=[], pos=(0, 0)):
    for xy in xy_arr:
        p.annotate(s, xy, pos,
                   arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.2", fc="w"))
```

Comment: Use an empty string for all but one of them?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Unfortunately, if i try that, by separating the first element of the xy_arr list from the rest, the arrows do not connect in the same way (they cross, have a different point of origin, etc).